# Get Cecaelia to walk

Tags: creature-design, merfolk

Cecaelia, classic mythological creature
Kind of a "water centaur" half human and half octopus, we've all seen it in that Disney mermaid movie. 
[image]

Question is, how do I get those squishy tentacle things to walk upright on land?

Only rule= no magic

Comment: @AlexP  https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/6227/is-there-an-older-name-for-cecaelia

Comment: Yes, the Japanese are fascinated with octopuses and tentacles. What does this have to do with classic mythology?

Comment: https://warriorsofmyth.fandom.com/wiki/Cecaelia   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoZMxOF54g8Come on everyone, play nice.  We don't have to get too literal.

Comment: [Not a duplicate but very relevant](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143124/anatomy-of-a-walking-octopoid?r=SearchResults)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## ***They already can:***

Your Cecaelia isn't going to necessarily be graceful on land, no matter what. If the human part can breathe air, you're half-way there already. Octupi [CAN walk on land](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebeNeQFUMa0) just awkwardly. The human part might be the hardest part to deal with, in fact. Some poles to maintain upright posture could be helpful. If an octopus slither isn't enough for your styling, just make the tentacles more muscular or give the Cecaelia really long arms to assist lifting it's weight. People without legs get around surprisingly well. Check [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjoOSnbb5RU) out, as your illustration is very muscular.

Comment: I feel pity for the crab by the end of the video. Poor creature didn't know what to do, and could mostly just watch as death crept over him.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in order for a creature to walk without magic, it must be able to survive. For a human-sized organism like the cecaelia, this will require that the creature have some sort of excretory organs, that are not present in the cecaelia presented in the question. A way to add these organs without making it too unlike a cecaelia, would be to add a mantle between the octopus tentactles and the human torso. However, this will make the cecaelia taller, and less able to walk. One way to make this cecaelia stronger and more able to walk would be to add a gladius in the mantle, which would articulate with the skeleton, and support the weight of the body. Finally, walking, or at least moving around on land, could be achieved by sliding along with the tentacles, using them similarly to a basal mollusc foot